# Android mobile to mobile communication offline mode

Tags: android

General question.  Im looking at writing an Android app that communication wise is a lot like say a chess game.  Player one opens his chess app, sends his "move" to as second player.  Second player may be powered off or what ever (i.e. he's offline) so it's not a live exchange.  Player 2 eventually goes online and receives the player 1 "move".  Now without using GCM which requires a Third party server, is there a way of doing mobile to mobile communication exchanges.  I was thinking of using just emails with attachments.  But perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: Actually, emails also require a third-party server.

Answer (score 0):

The normal answer for this is to use a server-  send the moves to a server, and download the moves from it.  Have the client ping the server every few minutes to check for moves.  Without a server, the only thing I can think of is SMS.  The problem is that SMS may be greatly delayed or delivered out of order.

So why don't you want to use a server?  It's really the right answer, either using GCM or a standard webservice.

Comment: The reason: I'm cheap.  I guess I could have the app poll a web server (like go daddy).  I read the gcm and for me the biggest issue is getting a live java server running.  It's like 80$ a month (as far as I can see)

Comment: That's overkill, and the only real advantage is push.  I'd go with an Amazon AWS instance, the small ones are really cheap, and if your app is popular you can scale.  

If people are in the same room you can use bluetooth, but I suspect that won't be the case.

Comment: So has anyone made a GCM server with Amazon AWS?  It seems to require some Java Server (tomcat)

Comment: AWS is just a plain linux box, you have to install all software on top of it.  So it can work, but you'll need to learn how to set up tomcat.  There may be a pre-designed image you can use, but I wouldn't know which.

Comment: Buy a Raspberry Pi, put Apache, PHP and MySQL on it. Run your own server, cheap, easy and hardly uses any power.